# Publishing Multi size Images in Google Web Desinger have ... scrollbars

Tags: google-web-designer

I'm realy buffled here, i'm getting scrolbars on my published multi size **images** in Google Web Deigner.

So, I just want to create multiple sizes of image ads in Google Web Designer.

I go to *File* / *New file* / and i select *Image (new)* and *multi size format*. In my *Responsive* window i select *multi-size layout*, and i select 2-3 different sizes (ie *300x250, 970x250, 300x600*).

[image: Creating a new file]

Next, i import some images in the *Library*, and i do my design setup for each size in *Edit Base document*. Then, i make the needed changes for every size.

Bare in mind that since my sizes are completely different, my imported image in some of them is bigger than my actual ad size and leaks out of the borders of the ad.

[image: Image bigger than the ad]

When i *Publish*, in every size that my image is bigger than the ad size, i get... scrollbars in my result.

[image: Preview image]

[image: Final image]

I'm using version 15.0.1.0922 In Windows 10

What i'm i doing wrong? I can't find any posted bug in Google Search, so, any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but no answer. I made the ad bigger and cut it out by hand.
New update really ain't good, Googles doing a very poor job.

Comment: Oh, i really hoped i was in the wrong here. It's terrifying to consider that a huge bug like that passed all the tests....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).